# Conditional validation with Joi

Tags: joi

I try to implement conditional validation with Joi. I have an endpoint that can accept either:

```js
{
    from: 'abc'
}
```

Or

```js
{
    type: 'some-type'
}
```

If the `type` field isn't present, the `from` field is mandatory and if the `from` field isn't present, the `type` field is mandatory. The `type` can only accept a set of values.

I tried the following approach without success:

```js
type: joi.alternatives().conditional('from', {
    is: joi.string().empty(), 
    then: joi.string().required().valid('val1', 'val2'),
    otherwise: joi.optional()
}).messages({
    'any.valid': 'type.not.supported.value',
    'any.required': 'type.required'
}),
from: joi.alternatives().conditional('type', {
    is: joi.string().empty(),
    then: joi.required(),
    otherwise: joi.optional() 
}).messages({
    'any.valid': 'from.not.supported.value',
    'any.required': 'from.required'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds like an [`or` constraint](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.2.1#objectorpeers-options).

> ...a relationship between keys where one of the peers is required (and more than one is allowed)

The following schema would work:

```js
joi.object().keys({
  type: joi.string().valid('val1', 'val2'),
  from: joi.string()
}).or('type', 'from');
```

Comment: It looks like to be the right approach. Will check that. Thanks very much for pointing this out!

Comment: @Ankh, it did not work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76406772/joi-conditional-validations